# Where is /data/data folder android

Tags: android

Ok, I am new to Android. And I have read somewhere about `/data/data` folder in Android. But nowhere on the web I found where does this folder point to. Can anybody please explain?

Comment: /data/data is the folder in a device(or emulator) where data of applications in the device is stored.. You can find  it with File Explorer from eclipse.

Comment: if u want to see in emulator that go to Windows>show view>File Explorer>data folder exits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/data/data` is a part of your device's internal storage, and where all apps are installed to. You cannot browse it directly unless you have a rooted device.

As for where it points to, it simply points to a part of your internal storage.

Comment: That means that files in it are private to that specific applicaton?

Comment: Can you specify what internal storage means? Where does it actually reside? And when does it get cleared?

Answer (score 1):

you cant see that folder in the device unless you rooted your device...but if you running in emulator then you can find that path in the DDMS Right Side of the your eclipse and then in that you will get this folder in `mnt >data >data`here is [link](http://denniskubes.com/2012/09/25/read-android-data-folder-without-rooting/) that will help you on this if you want to access withought root your device